# Why does my background end up black?

Tags: rendering, transparency

Whenever I try to render something with transparent activated, when I save it, the background is black. I'm using cycles. I go to Render Properties > Film > Transparent and I checked transparent. I also use png. What's going on? I'm new to blender by the way.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What image format do you use? Some formats (like jpg) don't support transparency.

Comment: i use png which worked fine for my other thing